# advanced paging in wordpress

Tags: pages, pagination

I can create pages in wordpress very simple like

```
www.mysite.com/profile
```

Now I have a question how can I make more pages in this page like `www.mysite.com/profile/edit` or maybe more pages like

```
 www.mysite.com/profile/edit/image
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case, if you are asking about nesting of pages, then you do the following -

1. Create the edit page, and make the profile page the parent of the same (you can see this take effect when you update the page and the url changes to www.mysite.com/profile/edit)
2. Similarly, create the image page, and make the edit page the parent of the same